# Xamarin.Forms setting specific style for platform

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, themes, xamarin.forms-styles

I'm trying to style my UWP application with some specific styles, while on other platforms it should remain default.

This is my project layout:

[image]

I tried the following things:
In `Clients.Shared` creating a style as following:

```
<Style x:Key="SomeStyle" TargetType="Button" />
```

And adding the same Style key in the `Clients.Themes.UWP` so it could hopefully override it, but no luck.

Then I tried Having a Dummy Style and using the `onPlatform` but that didn't work either, but I still think this is the way to go. I had the following code:

```
<Style x:Key="DummyStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Style">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnPlatform x:Key="ButtonStyle" x:TypeArguments="Style">
                <On Platform="UWP" Value="{StaticResource SomeStyle}"></On>
            </OnPlatform>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I tried messing around with merged `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries` but there I couldn't include the xaml

Anybody have any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" Android="Green" iOS="White" WinPhone="White"
        x:Key="PrimaryColor" />


<Style x:Key="ButtonColor" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" />
</Style>

<Button Text="Hello" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
   Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource ButtonColor}" />
```

In this example, I am defining a style for a Button called `ButtonColor`.  This Button will use a `BackgroundColor` of white for all platforms except Android where it will be Green.

I find this is the most common use for this tag with regard to styling; if you are working with fonts, be sure to run on simulator and actual devices to get the font that you want.

Comment: That does only colors, I want full on styles

Comment: Visual Studio is marking the `Android` etc properties on `OnPlatform` as obsolete. Any idea what the replacement is?

Comment: @Savage - in xaml, there is a newer "nested" syntax, that handles additional platforms cleanly. Look for discussion of `<OnPlatform><<On Platform="Android" Value=.../></OnPlatform>`. In c#, use `switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax works for me:

```
<Style x:Key="zoneLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
  <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="18" />
  <Setter Property="Margin">
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
      <On Platform="Android" Value="0, -3, 0, 0" />
    </OnPlatform>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use

```
<Button.Style>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Style">
        <OnPlatform.iOS>...</OnPlatform.iOS>
        <OnPlatform.Android>...</OnPlatform.Android>
        <OnPlatform.WinPhone>...</OnPlatform.WinPhone>
    </OnPlatform>
</Button.Style>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: The problem is that I can't load in the styles :)